# Resolving ambiguous external symbol references in Loadable Kernel Modules ( LKM )

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Lets suppose there are two loaded kernel modules that have exported two different functions as identically named symbols.  For example:
`MyFn` in `MyLKM1.ko`
`MyFn` in `MyLKM2.ko`

How does a third kernel module ( e.g. `MyLKM3.ko` ) disambiguate between these two external symbols when it wants to import the 'MyFn` symbol in order to do its code relocation when it gets loaded?

P.S.
*I am not looking for instructions how to build kernel modules.
I am looking for a description of the mechanism for ambiguous external symbol resolution in LKMs as ELF files.*

Comment: There is only one definition of each symbol.  See depmod.

Comment: If it is impossible to export two symbols with the same name, then it answers my question.  Unfortunately I have no answer to accept :(